# How to show selected value from dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

I have a table with 3 columns. The first is name of the student. The second column is a dropdown, in which it should be selected the teacher that teaches this student from first column and the other values in this dropdown  should be other teachers and it could change teacher.And third column is submit button - to save changes (if you have changed the teacher for this student). I use `"selected=selected"`, but it selects in all rows only one teacher, not dependent on what is in db.Here's my view:

```php
foreach ($students_show as $row)
{

?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php echo $row->username; 
</td>
<?php
echo "<select name = 'add_teacher[]' >";
    foreach($teachers_show as $row) 
    {

        ?>
        <option value= '$row->username '
        <?php echo $row->username == $row->username  ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $row->username ; ?></option>


    <?php 
  } 
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </td>
```

My model is:

```php
public function stdents_show()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('role_id', '2');
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
    }
       public function teacher_show()
    {

        $this->db->select('teacher_id, users.username');
        $this->db->from('teacher_conn');
        $this->db->distinct('teacher_id');
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id=teacher_conn.teacher_id');

        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
    }
```

Comment: Is this codeigniter ?

Comment: Yes, it's CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `$row` for both student and teacher.
use this way :

```
foreach ($students_show as $student)
```

and

```
foreach($teachers_show as $teacher)
```

and compare should be like this

```
<?php echo $teacher->username == $student->teahcer_name? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $teacher->username ; ?></option>
```

Comment: I made it that: foreach ($students_show as $student) And foreach($teachers_show as $teacher) but they are not equal: $teacher->username == $student->teahcer_name. It must show that teacher, which studies this student. My database table is: id, teacher_id, student_id. They are in one row-something like where in queries. But how to use it in dropdown:   $this->db->where('teacher_id', $this->input->post('teacher_id')); - this doesn't show any results if I use it in my query.